# Convert API response to proper case

Tags: node.js

I am building a new API service in NodeJS and the API that I calling is returning me JSON but all the keys start with uppercase. Example `AccountNumber: '2342222'`. I want to convert that so its `accountNumber`. Is there a library that will do this for me or do I need to loop through and update each one?

Comment: There is the camelCase piece which is a duplicate, but there is also an Object Mapping over keys piece

Comment: @ben-fortune That link is for converting any string. I am working with JSON data.

Comment: @jrock2004 It's the same, your key is a string.